# Make Backbone fetch not update models

Tags: backbone.js, fetch, backbone-relational

I'm trying to fetch some related models using Backbone, using [backbone-relational.js](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational), and keep this action mutually exclusive from some other models/collections I have in memory.  Example:

```
user = new Backbone.User { id: 1 }
user.fetch() # also fetches user.posts, using RABL

user_posts = @user.get('posts') # Using backbone-relational.js
first_post = @user_posts.get(1)

first_post.get('title') # => 'Old title'
first_post.set({ title: 'Some new title' }) # or whatever

posts = new Backbone.Posts()
posts.fetch()
posts.get(1).get('title') # => 'Old title'
first_post.get('title') # => 'Old title'
```

Now it would seem that these two things should be unrelated, and `first_post` should still have 'Some new title', but it doesn't.  : (  This is causing issues with state in some parts of my program, and it's pretty obnoxious.

I should be clear, I *want* `first_post.get('title')` to keep its new value, `'Some new title'`, without calling `first_post.save()`.

EDIT: I'm thinking now that it's something backbone-relational is doing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i've never seen this kind of behavior before, and i've never used backbone-relational either. my initial guess is that it has something to do with BB-R, and not backbone itself. i added the BB-R tag to your post, so hopefully someone else can chime in on that

Comment: Thanks.  After some investigation I believe you are correct.

Comment: It seems to be related to this issue here: https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/issues/135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be related to the backone-relational plugin: https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/issues/135